# angular 6 project that keep crasing and trhow Incompatibility erros

Tags: angular, angular-cli, web-deployment, angular6

i just started to learn angular 6 
and i downloaded [this](https://github.com/AmitXShukla/DEMO-Angular-6-Login-Auth) project (login system with Firebase) i just wanted to learn how to achieve that by my self from that code.. 
i fixed some bugs with help of google but now every time that i try to use any npm install up date or whatever it put me this error

```
@angular/core@4.4.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@6.1.7 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@6.1.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@6.1.7 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@6.1.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-material@1.1.10 requires a peer of angular-animate@1.4 - 1.7.0 || ^1.7.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-material@1.1.10 requires a peer of angular-aria@1.4 - 1.7.0 || ^1.7.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular-material@1.1.10 requires a peer of angular-messages@1.4 - 1.7.0 || ^1.7.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/animations@4.4.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/common@4.4.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/compiler@4.4.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser@4.4.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.4.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/router@4.4.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself
```

can anyone tell me what this errors means and how to fix them? 
its my first days in web dev (i know html javascript and css ) but angular 6 is bit a hard for me

i try the guide to upgrade the angular version and still show me the same errors

Answer (score 0):

They are warnings, not errors. 
In any case you can try this

`ng update`

`rm -rf node_modules`

`npm install`

It will upgrade all angular modules, then remove existing modules before reinstalling all of them.

Anyhow, I would personally recommend that you create a new project from CLI with latest dependencies:

`npm i -g @angular/cli@latest`

`ng new myProject`

Then paste in the code you want to run in the new project.

Angular changed a lot in their configs over the course of the last versions and your project is at version 4.x, meanwhile Angular by now is in the 6.x range.

Answer (score 0):

While developers pushing their codes to github, they are using .gitignore file. And this file configures which files and folders will not push to repository. Because of this you have to run `npm install` first, and this code will install the dependencies which are used in the project. They are defined in the package.json file.

After running `npm install` you can use `npm start` or `ng serve -o`